# making function accept the path that's inside the string variable

Tags: c++

I have a string variable called `b1`.

That variable is holding a path.

I need to get the "remove" function to take that path from the variable `b1`

Here is my code...

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

string a1 = "W:\\ftp\\4CS\\DL\\";
string a2;

int getdir (string dir, vector<string> &files)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;

    if((dp = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL)
    {
    cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl;
    return errno;
    }
    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
std::string fname = dirp->d_name;
if(fname.find("te") != std::string::npos)
    files.push_back(fname);
}
}

int main()
{

string catcher;

    string dir = string(a1);
    vector<string> files = vector<string>();

    getdir(dir,files);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < files.size();)
{
        //cout << files[i] << endl;

        a2 = files[i];

        cout << a2 << endl;

string b1 = a1 + a2;

cout << b1 << endl;

//const int result = remove("W:\\ftp\\4CS\\DL\\testng it.txt");

char filename[] = b1;

/*  Deletes the file if exists */
if (remove(filename) != 0)
    perror("File deletion failed");
else
    cout << "File deleted successfully";

return 0;

i++;

}

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wtf was that thing at the end of the question? (check edit history)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat eminem

Comment: Please try and fix the indentation of the source code presented. Improvement to code comments an spacing welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple

```
remove(b1.c_str());
```

call c_str() to get a pointer to a C string from a C++ string.

Comment: dear god, thank you. You should be hired by google today